# Particle modifier object deformation problem

Tags: modifiers, instances

Im trying to make custom modeled monster tentacle to deform on the particle system hairs with the hair intance modifier. Particle system is animated with the turbulence field and working as expected. When i apply particle instance modifier the tentacles are oriented properly but loosing volume during the movement. Is there a way to preserve volume of the deformed geometry?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Looks like they could use additional subdivisions, not sure if that alone solves the issue